# Filtering data and labeling them based on threshold issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to set a threshold with different criteria to label data points into categories

So my code is this

```
C1_C2 = read.csv("C1_C2_contrast.txt")
diff_C1_C2 <- C1_C2 %>%
  mutate(UP_DOWN = case_when(
   # padj < 0.05 & log2FoldChange > 1.5 & log2FoldChange < 2.5~ "UP", 
    baseMean > 50 & pvalue < 0.05 & log2FoldChange > 1.2 ~ "UP",
    baseMean > 50 &  pvalue < 0.05 & log2FoldChange <  0.7 & log2FoldChange > -1.2 ~ "DOWN",
    baseMean > 50 & pvalue < 0.05 & log2FoldChange <  -1.3 ~ "Low",
    TRUE ~ 'NS'))
```

The issue here is I'm either missing some of the data-points which are labelled as NS or non significant.My data [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INO4ytSxzF0pJ5l4gfFII89i0nAvLpiA/view?usp=sharing)

For example based on my criteria

```
gene  Symbol baseMean log2FoldChange   lfcSE     stat       pvalue        padj UP_DOWN
10718 ENSMUSG00000062488 Ifit3b  30.60793       5.406398 1.45993 3.703191 0.0002129046 0.001601761      NS
```

This gene should be labelled as UP given it `baseMean` is > 50 ,`pvalue` < 0.05 and `log2FoldChange` is 5

similarly if i go the negative threshold the below gene should be lalelled as Low but it is labelled as NS.

```
 gene  Symbol baseMean log2FoldChange    lfcSE      stat      pvalue         padj UP_DOWN
1887 ENSMUSG00000020620 Abca8b  40.18724      -5.775263 1.499373 -3.851787 0.000117259 0.0009731761      NS
```

Its a very simple issue but I can't figure out what issue in my criteria to filter and label

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or what, in your code you set `baseMean > 50` but in your text you said `basemean > 20`

Comment: typo ...baseMean this is what i meant ..i was tying it so..

Comment: modified it the question

Comment: I mean in your actual `case_when` statement you use 50 but in your text you use 20

Comment: okay sorry that was type basemean is 50 i just skipped your comment , 50 is actual

Comment: Then gene 10718 and 1887 are both correctly labelled as "NS", since the baseMean is < 50 in both cases (note you've used **AND** `&` in your `case_when`)

Comment: yes it does ..not sure where did i miss.!!!.is my code that case when is correct? logically

Comment: Sorry again I do see this ' gene Symbol baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue         padj UP_DOWN
5278 ENSMUSG00000029804 Herc3  372.2593      -1.294242 0.1268097 -10.20618 1.860553e-24 2.854866e-22      NS' my baseMean theshold was > 20 it is not matching